# What is the problem for using fullPage.js moveTo?

Tags: javascript, django, fullpage.js

I want to make a button to move a specific page...like if I click the `#move_to_slide2`, then the page moves to slide2, but the moveTo function doesn't work.

There is only one section and 4 slides.

How can I make the move to button?

```html
<div class="section" anchor="s0">
    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1">
        <div class="container w-1/3 mx-auto">
            <div class="my-40">
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="text-xl font-bold text-center text-unifolio-blue">Getting Started</div>
                    <div class="flex w-full mt-5 items-center justify-center">
                        <p id="move_to_slide1">
                        <p class="w-full h-6 rounded-full bg-unifolio-blue cursor-pointer"></p>
                        </p>
                        <div class="h-px w-full bg-gray-400"></div>
                        <p id="move_to_slide2">
                        <p class="w-full h-6 rounded-full bg-gray-400 cursor-pointer"></p>
                        </p>
                        <div class="h-px w-full bg-gray-400"></div>
                        <p id="move_to_slide3">
                        <p class="w-full h-6 rounded-full bg-gray-400 cursor-pointer"></p>
                        </p>
                        <div class="h-px w-full bg-gray-400"></div>
                        <div class="flex w-full mb-5 items-center text-center justify-center">
                            <p id="move_to_slide1">
                            <p class="w-full h-6 text-xs text-unifolio-blue cursor-pointer">아이디 및 비밀번호 설정</p>
                            </p>
                            <div class="h-px w-full bg-white"></div>
                            <p id="move_to_slide2">
                            <p class="w-full h-6 text-xs text-gray-400 cursor-pointer">개인정보 입력</p>
                            </p>
                            <div class="h-px w-full bg-white"></div>
                            <p id="move_to_slide3">
                            <p class="w-full h-6 text-xs text-gray-400 cursor-pointer">핸드폰 인증</p>
                            </p>
                            <div class="h-px w-full bg-white"></div>
```

this is my script.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            //options here
            autoScrolling:true,
            scrollHorizontally: true
        });
        $('#move_to_slide1').click(function(){
        fullpage_api.moveTo(1,slide1);
        });
        $('#move_to_slide2').click(function(){
        fullpage_api.moveTo(1,slide2);
        });
        $('#move_to_slide3').click(function(){
        fullpage_api.moveTo(1,slide3);
        });
        $('#move_to_slide4').click(function(){
        fullpage_api.moveTo(1,slide4);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the correct parameters to `moveTo`.*
2nd param should be the slide anchor **string** or the slide index.

For example:

```
fullpage_api.moveTo(1, 1); // using slide index
fullpage_api.moveTo(1, 'slide1');  // using slide anchor
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but, it doesn't work. my div class is section and slide(slide1,2,3,4) but the moveTo doesn't work. Is there any other method to it work? please refer below architecture:
<div id="fullpage">
            <div class="section" anchor="s0">
                <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1"></div>
                <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2"></div>
                <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide3"></div>
                <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide4"></div>
</div></div>

Comment: You can see a working example here: http://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/doqOmY and you can find more about how to use it [in the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#movetosection-slide)